# Induced norm question.

Tags: normed-spaces

I'd like to show that the induced 1-norm satisfies:
$\|A\|_1=\max_{1 \le j \le n}\sum_{i=1}^n |a_{i,j}|$

I'd appreciate some guidance.

Comment: By induced 1-norm, do you mean the operator norm on matrices induced by the 1-norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ (or $\mathbb{C}^n$)?

Comment: That is exactly what I meant :).

Comment: Every column is the result of using $A$ to act on a standard basis. In other word, that sum $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}|a_{i,j}|$ is just the norm $||Ax||$ where $x$ is a j-th basis.

Comment: And to amplify on what @Gina says, that shows the inequality $\|A\|_1\ge\max_{1 \le j \le n}\sum_{i=1}^n |a_{i,j}|$. So now only the opposite inequality remains.

Comment: @Gina yes, but we want $||A||_1$, not $||Ax||_1$ for some $x$

Comment: @GPerez:it's INDUCED norm.

Comment: @Gina No offence meant, I just thought it wasn't clear in your comment that $||A||$ considers $||Ax||$ for a whole bunch of $x$'s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the definition of $||A||_1$, which is: $$||A||_1 = \max_{||x||_1=1}{||Ax||_1}$$
So say we have $x\in\mathbb R^n$ (assume $A$ is $n\times n$), with $||x||_1=1$, which means: $$(1) \quad \sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_i| = 1$$ 
Now we want to find the maximum of the set (of real numbers) $\{||Ax||\text{ such that } ||x||_1 =1\}$=$U$. For any number in this set,$$q\in U\Rightarrow q=||Ax||_1 = ||\sum_{j=1}^n x_j\vec{a_j}||_1$$
where $\vec{a_j}$ is the $j$-th column of $A$ (whose columns happen to be vectors in $\mathbb R^n$, of which the $1$-norm can be taken), so by the triangle inequality we have $$q \le\sum_{j=1}^n ||x_j\vec{a_j}||_1 = \sum_{j=1}^n |x_j|\ ||\vec{a_j}||_1$$
Because every $||\vec{a_j}||_1$ has a positive coefficient, the total sum is less than or equal to replacing every $||\vec{a_j}||_1$ with the maximum of them all, $\max_{j}{||\vec{a_j}||_1}$, which we'll call $M$. So we have $$q \le\sum_{j=1}^n |x_j|M = M\sum_{j=1}^n |x_j|\stackrel{\text{(1)}} = M\cdot1 = M = \max_{1\le j\le n}{||\vec{a_j}||_1} = \max_{1\le j\le n}{\sum_{i=1}^n |a_{i,j}|}, \text{ QED.}$$

So far we have proved that for any $q\in U$, $q\le\max_{1\le j\le n}\sum_{i=1}^n |a_{i,j}|$. For a set in $\mathbb R^n$, the maximum is defined as the real number that: 1) is greater than or equal to any number in the set, and 2) is in the set. We've proved that $\max_{1\le j\le n}\sum_{i=1}^n |a_{i,j}|$ satisfies 1). Now, note that $\sum_{i=1}^n |a_{i,j}|=||\sum_{i=1}^n Ae_j||_1$, where $e_j$ is the j-th standard basis vector in $\mathbb R^n$(all zeros and a $1$ in the $j$-th position). Since $||e_j||_1 = 0 +\dotsb+0+1+0+\dotsb+0 = 1$, by definition $\sum_{i=1}^n |a_{i,j}|$ is in $U$ and therefore satisfies 2), and therefore is the maximum of $U$.

Comment: Please don't resent me for writing that, alas, I still don't quite understand how to assemble all the above pieces together :/. Any further advice?

Comment: @Harald Hanche-Olsen, how exactly did you determine the direction of the inequality you wrote?

Comment: Referring to GPerez - how and why would you make use of a basis vector here? I am not sure I understand and would appreciate some explanaion. I did manage to understand Gina's comment about x being the j-th basis.

Comment: The basis vector is actually needed to complete the proof, to show that $M$ (in the response) is indeed in $U$, that is, that $M = ||Ax||_1$ for some $x$ with $||x||_1 = 1$

Comment: Referring to GPerez - Could you please explain the last equality in your proof? Aren't you in fact using a property which you are actually asked to prove? Also, that only proves one direction. Shouldn't Harald Hanche-Olsen's comment about the second direction be added in order to complete the proof? Furthermore, how was the direction of that inequality determined, i.e. why did Gina's comment entail that q (in your proof) was greater or equal to?

Comment: @Grtv, in the last equality, note that $\vec{a_j}$ is a vector in $\mathbb R^n$ with components $(a_{1j},\dots,a_{ij},\dots,a_{nj})$, so its 1-norm is defined as $\sum_{i=1}^n |a_{i,j}|$. So the equality comes from substituting in the definition of 1-norm of a vector. I've edited to add the completion of the proof.

Comment: What do you mean by "I've edited to add the completion of the proof."? And how was the other direction of that inequality obtained?

Comment: Now it's edited, sorry, wasn't done yet. And the two-inequalities-proof, (call $M=\max_{1 \le j \le n}\sum_{i=1}^n |a_{i,j}|$) namely $\|A\|_1\ge M$ and $\|A\|_1\le M$, notice that, at the end of the edited proof, proof of 1) proves "$\le$", and 2) proves "$\ge$". What I mean is, my proof doesn't explicitly prove the two inequalities, but if needed it can be shown to be equivalent to doing so (which it should, otherwise it would be no proof at all).

Comment: I see it now. Thank you very much! :-)

Comment: GPerez, something small still bothers me in your proof, namely - you've shown that the sum itself is in U but not that M (i.e. the maximum of the sum) is in U. Please comment.

Comment: I think your confused about the meaning of the expression $\max_{1 \le j \le n}\sum_{i=1}^n |a_{i,j}|$. $\sum_{i=1}^n |a_{i,j}|$ means the sum of the elements of the $j$-th column of $A$, and $\max_{1 \le j \le n}$ means the maximum over all $j$'s, ergo all column sums. Since any column sum is in $U$, as we've shown, and the maximum is one of those sums, the maximum is also in $U$.